# TreeView, ObjectDataProvider, HierarchicalDataTemplate, xsd2Code not showing anything

Tags: wpf, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate, objectdataprovider

I have an object hierarchy created with xsd2code. The object hierarchy
consist of a root object of type Project which contains an ObservableCollection
of Folder named folder which is a recursive object containing ObservableCollection
of Folder named folder and File named file
I want to bind this object hierarchy to a TreeView thru an ObjectDataProvider
and control the display thru HierarchicalDataTemplate definitions

The ObjectDataProvider and DataTemplates are defined in a resource merged in App.xaml like this

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="projectTemplate"
    DataType="{x:Type model:Project}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=folder}"                     
    >
    <Grid ToolTip="{Binding Path=Name}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="16" />

            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Source="Images/folder_documents_512.ico"  Grid.Column="0"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="6,0,0,0"
        Text="{Binding Path=Name}" 
        />
    </Grid>

</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate
    DataType="{x:Type model:Folder}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=file}">
    <Grid ToolTip="{Binding Path=name}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="16" />

            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Source="Images/folder_vectors_512.ico"  Grid.Column="0"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="6,0,0,0"
        Text="{Binding Path=name}" 
        />
    </Grid>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>



<DataTemplate
    DataType="{x:Type model:File}">
    <Grid ToolTip="{Binding Path=name}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="16" />

            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Source="Images/article-24.png"  Grid.Column="0"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="6,0,0,0"
        Text="{Binding Path=name}" 
        />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>


<ObjectDataProvider
    x:Key="project"

   >
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

The TreeView is defined like this

```
    <TreeView x:Name="tvProject"  
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource project}}"
            >
```

The global processing is : I load the object hierarchy from an Xml file (xsd2code functionality). As I can see in debug my object hierarchy is clean.
Then, I bind the object hierarchy to the ObjectDataProvider in code like this

```
ObjectDataProvider dp = Application.Current.FindResource("project") as ObjectDataProvider;
        dp.ObjectInstance = _project;
```

Well, nothing appears in  the TreeView.
What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue,

First, I had to bound a collection to the ObjectDataProvider and not just a single object. I don´t think this is an ObjectDataProvider requirement but more a requirement for HierarchicalDataTemplate.

```
ObjectDataProvider dp = Application.Current.FindResource("project") as ObjectDataProvider;
ArrayList ocp = new ArrayList();
ocp.Add(_project);
dp.ObjectInstance = ocp;
```

Then I had to chain the reference to the different DataTemplates thru the ItemTemplate property like this:

First on the TreeView

```
 <TreeView x:Name="tvProject"  
           ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource project}}"
           ItemTemplate="{StaticResource projectTemplate}"
                >
```

And then in the diferent DataTemplate

```
   <DataTemplate x:Key="fileTemplate"
        DataType="{x:Type model:File}">
        <Grid ToolTip="{Binding Path=name}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="16" />

                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Source="Images/article-24.png"  Grid.Column="0"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="6,0,0,0"
            Text="{Binding Path=name}" 
            />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>



    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="folderTemplate"
        DataType="{x:Type model:Folder}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=file}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource fileTemplate}">
        <Grid ToolTip="{Binding Path=name}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="16" />

                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Source="Images/folder_vectors_512.ico"  Grid.Column="0"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="6,0,0,0"
            Text="{Binding Path=name}" 
            />
        </Grid>

    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>


    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="projectTemplate"
        DataType="{x:Type model:Project}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=folder}"  
       ItemTemplate="{StaticResource folderTemplate}"
        >
        <Grid ToolTip="{Binding Path=Name}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="16" />

                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Source="Images/folder_documents_512.ico"  Grid.Column="0"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="6,0,0,0"
            Text="{Binding Path=Name}" 
            />
        </Grid>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Now it works

**EDIT**

Since Collection can give back different types (i.e Folder and File)
you need a template selector

```
public class FileSystemObjectTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public override DataTemplate
            SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;

            if (element != null && item != null && item is FileSystemObject)
            {
                if (item is File)
                    return Application.Current.FindResource("fileTemplate") as DataTemplate;

                if (item is Folder)
                    return Application.Current.FindResource("folderTemplate") as DataTemplate;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

and the call it in the XAML

```
<local:FileSystemObjectTemplateSelector  x:Key="FileSystemObjectTemplateSelector" />

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="folderTemplate"
        DataType="{x:Type model:Folder}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=fsObjects, Converter={StaticResource SortFoldersAndFiles}}"
                            ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource FileSystemObjectTemplateSelector}" >

    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```